# Sublime Text 3 don't load menu itens and plugins in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sublimetext, sublimetext3, ubuntu-13.04

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu 13.04. But the second time an error with menu items and plugins, both not carry occurred.

Example, in the picture below there are two errors, menu itens and a plugin (in this case, SideBarEnhancements).

[image: Exemple]

p.s: my pastes in `.config` of Sublime Text 3 are with permission to my user.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console? Use `View -> Show Console` to see.

Comment: The console is also not available :/ http://i.imgur.com/uyw9NYy.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a drastic solution, but try running the following after quitting Sublime:

```
mv ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User ~
rm -rf ~/.config/sublime-text-3
```

You're going to have to set up all your preferences and plugins again, but backing up the `Packages/User` folder will help with that.

If even that doesn't work, you'll have to reinstall Sublime. The best way is to download the appropriate Ubuntu `.deb` file, then install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_buildXXXX.deb
```

replacing the file name with the one you downloaded.

I'm not sure exactly what is happening, but something is seriously messed up. Make sure that when you run Sublime again for the first time after following the steps above that you do it as your regular user, not using `sudo`.

Good luck!

Comment: Be sure you move the `sublime-text-3` directory not the ST2 one.

Comment: I tried to do these steps before and didn't work. I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: @skuroda oops, missed that. Thanks!